# Can no declare a simple variable of type "var"

Tags: java

Why does Netbeans not recognize `var` as a class?

The error that results is:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: class: var
location: class excell
```

Here is the code (of course simplified):

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Excell {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        var r = 0.1;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Java is strong type language. This means each variable must has its type defined. It is not JavaScript that you can use `var` type and the language interpretor will guess its type. I would recommend to use `double r = 0.1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not have a local wildcard type such as JavaScript's `var`. See the [tutorial on variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Specify the [type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) instead:

```
String aString;
int anInteger;
double aDouble;
FooClass instanceOfSomeClass;
```

In your code example you will want a `double` as you have a numeric value that is not an integer.

Javascript also uses `var` to make a variable local. You do not need to do this explicitly. All variables *declared* in methods, constructors, initializer blocks, lambdas, etc, are local while everything declared at class scope is a field.

If you need a wildcard-like type, use `Object`. Any reference type is assignable and any primitive can be boxed.

Comment: Ah!, i feel bad myself lol. Dididnt know that difference betwen javascript and java. I am totally at java. So to declare somtehing like this

Comment: srry like this: var w = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); do i need to use Object instead var?.

Comment: @DanielRamirez You would use `ActiveXObject w = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");`. This falls under the example of `FooClass instanceOfSomeClass`. Java is a strongly-typed language.

Comment: By the way, my simple objective for now is simply open an excell file that is located in my local disk using java. Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: @DanielRamirez No problem! If this answer helped you get started, and answered your question sufficiently, feel free to mark the checkmark at the left. It will mark this answer as having solved your problem and award you a bit of rep. (full disclosure: I am telling you this because it also carries a benefit for me)